# Using RSA key with chilkat API in C

Tags: c, rsa, ssh-keys, chilkat

I tried to use the RSA key from my .ssh directory using chilkat API in C but failed.
Does anyone have such experience?

Here is what I did so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "/home/germaneau/opt/chilkat/chilkat-9.5.0-x86-linux-gcc/include/C_CkSsh.h"
#include "/home/germaneau/opt/chilkat/chilkat-9.5.0-x86-linux-gcc/include/C_CkFtp2.h"
#include "/home/germaneau/opt/chilkat/chilkat-9.5.0-x86-linux-gcc/include/C_CkSshKey.h"

void testFtp2Create(void)
    {
    HCkFtp2 ftp;
    BOOL success;

    ftp = CkFtp2_Create();

    //  Any string unlocks the component for the 1st 30-days.
    success = CkFtp2_UnlockComponent(ftp,"Anything for 30-day trial");
    if (success != TRUE) {
        printf("%s\n",CkFtp2_lastErrorText(ftp));
    }

    CkFtp2_Dispose(ftp);
    }


void SSHSample(void)
    {
    HCkSsh ssh;
    BOOL success;
    const char * hostname;
    long port;
    long channelNum;
    const char * cmdOutput;
    HCkString privKey;
    HCkSshKey key;

    //  Important: It is helpful to send the contents of the
    //  ssh.LastErrorText property when requesting support.

    ssh = CkSsh_Create();
    key = CkSshKey_Create();

    //  Any string automatically begins a fully-functional 30-day trial.

    success = CkSsh_UnlockComponent(ssh,"Anything for 30-day trial");
    if (success != TRUE) {
        printf("%s\n",CkSsh_lastErrorText(ssh));
        return;
    }

    //  Connect to an SSH server:

    //  Hostname may be an IP address or hostname:
    hostname = "202.120.32.202";
    port = 22;

    success = CkSsh_Connect(ssh,hostname,port);
    if (success != TRUE) {
        printf("%s\n",CkSsh_lastErrorText(ssh));
        return;
    }

    //  Wait a max of 5 seconds when reading responses..
    CkSsh_putIdleTimeoutMs(ssh,5000);

    // load RSA key
    success = CkSshKey_LoadText(key,"/home/germaneau/.ssh/id_rsa",privKey);
    if (CkSshKey_getIsPrivateKey(key)) printf("PrivateKey\n");
    if (CkSshKey_getIsRsaKey(key)) printf("RsaKey\n");

    //  Authenticate using login/privkey:
    success = CkSsh_AuthenticatePk(ssh,"eric",key);
    if (success != TRUE) {
        printf("%s\n",CkSsh_lastErrorText(ssh));
        return;
    }

    //  Open a session channel.  (It is possible to have multiple
    //  session channels open simultaneously.)

    channelNum = CkSsh_OpenSessionChannel(ssh);
    if (channelNum < 0) {
        printf("%s\n",CkSsh_lastErrorText(ssh));
        return;
    }

    //  In this example, we'll copy wine.html to wine2.html
    //  The "cp" command has no output (i.e. nothing is written to
    //  the standard output) so we'll include an "echo FINISHED"
    //  so we can programmatically retrieve the output and close
    //  the channel.  Closing the channel immediately after sending
    //  the command is not good because w/ some SSH servers
    //  it introduces a race condition where the command may not
    //  be executed if the server thinks the client has disconnected.
    success = CkSsh_SendReqExec(ssh,channelNum,"echo STARTED && hostname && echo FINISHED");
    if (success != TRUE) {
        printf("%s\n",CkSsh_lastErrorText(ssh));
        return;
    }

    //  Read the channel until we receive the FINISHED string.
    success = CkSsh_ChannelReceiveUntilMatch(ssh,channelNum,"FINISHED","ansi",TRUE);
    if (success != TRUE) {
        printf("%s\n",CkSsh_lastErrorText(ssh));
        return;
    }

    //  Close the channel:
    success = CkSsh_ChannelSendClose(ssh,channelNum);
    if (success != TRUE) {
        printf("%s\n",CkSsh_lastErrorText(ssh));
        return;
    }

    //  Let's pickup the accumulated output of the command:
    //  (In this case, it will be the string "FINISHED")

    cmdOutput = CkSsh_getReceivedText(ssh,channelNum,"ansi");
    if (cmdOutput == 0 ) {
        printf("%s\n",CkSsh_lastErrorText(ssh));
        return;
    }

    //  Display the remote shell's command output:
    printf("%s\n",cmdOutput);

    //  Disconnect
    CkSsh_Disconnect(ssh);

    CkSsh_Dispose(ssh);

    }


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        printf("FTP\n");
    testFtp2Create();
        printf("OK\n");
        printf("SSH\n");        
    SSHSample();
        printf("OK\n"); 
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output I get:

```
FTP
OK
SSH
RsaKey
ChilkatLog:
  AuthenticatePk:
    DllDate: Mar  7 2014
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.17
    UnlockPrefix: Anything for 30-day trial
    Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
    Language: Linux C/C++
    VerboseLogging: 0
    SshVersion: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
    The SSH key object did not contain a loaded private key.
    Failed.
  --AuthenticatePk
--ChilkatLog

OK
```

I just don't understand why I get the message

- *The SSH key object did not contain a loaded private key.*

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and how does it fail? Post some code, please. Also, what format is the RSA key in? If possible, show us what the input looks like. (Maybe generate a new key, since you probably don't want to give the internet your private key.)